# How to display a modal and execute action at the same time

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf

I have this piece of code in my JSF page:

```
<a href="#adios" data-toggle="modal">
<h:commandButton value="Pay!" action="#{basketManager.pay(accountManager.currentAccount.username)}" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"></h:commandButton>
</a>
```

The modal displays, but the `action` is not executed... How can I perform both actions (Show modal and invoke the method) at the same time?

Comment: Why do you have a submit inside a link in the first place?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well is not that I want the "link" I just wanted to reference the script, so it activated when I pressed the button. Is there another way to run the script when I press this button rather than using a link? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand name="callAction" onstart="Place your javascript code to show the model"
       action="#{basketManager.pay(accountManager.currentAccount.username)}"  
       update="@form" />
    <h:commandButton value="Pay!" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
                     onclick="callAction();" />
 </h:form>
```

Here You can call you ManagedBean methods on javascript function.
When the remote-command starts it execution it shows the model and even call's the action method

Hope this helps you

Comment: It is throwing me the following error: Class 'org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUploadRenderer' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem. Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: `<p:commandButton value="Pay!" update="@form" action="#{basketManager.pay(accountManager.currentAccount.username)}" />`

Comment: @JeanCarlosSuárezMarranzini just a simple question, is your `UICommand` i.e. `<h:commandButton>` inside a `<h:form>`?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, it is inside a `<h:form>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform the script when you submit a form you could use  `onclick="alert('Clicked submit button!');"` event inside your commandButton tag.

One of ways to perform both actions is using `@ManagedProperty` annotation in your bean.
For example change your sumbit buton to this one

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Pay!" action="#{basketManager.pay()}" 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="alert('Clicked submit button!');" />
</h:form>
```

then your Bean could be more like this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "basketManager")
@RequestScoped
public class BasketManager implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{accountManager}")
    private AccountManager accountManager;

    //this is nessesery!
    public void setAccountManager(AccountManager accountManager) {
        this.accountManager = accountManager;
    }

    public String pay() {
        if(accountManager != null) {
            //... do something using accountManager.currentAccount.username
        }
        return ""; // your action result
    }
}
```

You have to remember that BasketManager bean must be in same or smaller scope than AccountManager bean. For example if AccountManager is `@SessionScoped` then BasketManager could be `@SessionScoped` or `@ViewScoped` or `@RequestScoper`. It cannot be `@ApplicationScoped` then!